# Join two tables query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables users and linkage. I am creating a link between one user to another. Means user A will be linked to user B and vise versa.

Now I want to get the details of linked users for a particular entered user_id. Means If user A is finding his linked Id's then the details of linked id's should be seen.

Linkage has three columns its id, user_id and linked_contact_id.
Users has columns as user_id, user_name,pass etc..

I tried one join but I only get the linked Id's from this not the details of id's.

```
SELECT * FROM Users INNER JOIN linkage ON linkage.user_id = Users.user_id WHERE linkage.linked_contact_id = 1
```

output

```
user_id  linked_contact_id
1              4 
1              1
1              5
```

How can I get this?Please help.. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to join on the users table a second time:

```
SELECT u.*, u2.* FROM Users u
INNER JOIN linkage l ON l.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN Users u2 ON l.linked_contact_id = u2.user_id
WHERE l.linked_contact_id = 1
```

Please note that as you are selecting the same columns twice (in `u.*, u2.*`), you will probably have to list out each field with an alias to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0):

Get Users information

```
SELECT users.*,
           linkage.*,
           contact.user_id as contact_user_id, 
           contact.user_name AS contact_user_name 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN linkage ON linkage.user_id = users.user_id 
INNER JOIN users AS contact ON linkage.linked_contact_id = contact.user_id 
WHERE linkage.linked_contact_id = 1
```

[image]

**Edit**

Here Screenshot of Query Output

[image]

Comment: I want all details of all linked Id's for a user not only one. @Naveen D Almeida

Comment: Above query returns the All the linked Id's for a user. @Sid

Comment: I want to get the details of the linked_contact_id's, linked_contact_id is nothing else but the another user. So If A is a user and A has B,C,D as linked contacts, then I want to show the details of All linked contacts of A i.e B,C and D. @ Naveen D Almeida

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong on your ratio. But it's okay.

Try LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN

```
SELECT * users
LEFT JOIN linkage

ON linkage.user_id = users.user_id

WHERE linkage.linked_contact_id = 1
```